# call finish callback when finishing other internal dependent finish callback method

Tags: c#, callback

I have a method **myobj_EndInteractionEvt** that is executed when an event occurs

In main class I register like:

```
//on main class register method passing args like
lo.myobj.EndInteractionEvt += (s, args) => updateInteraction(lo.myobj_EndInteractionEvt(s, args));

//this is called when finish executin "lo.myobj_EndInteractionEvt" 
public void updateInteraction(AOItour  tour)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tour.StateOfAOItour );  
    ClearMsg();
    etc...
}
```

Inside myobj class I call **myobj_EndInteractionEvt** which returns an object **AOItour**

```
internal AOItour  myobj_EndInteractionEvt(vtkObject losender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff and return AOItour
    return AOItour;
}
```

this works as it is needed (mostly because I am working on **vtk** and this needs to use lots of callbacks), the issue comes as myobj has an other callback **angleEndInteractionEvt** that updates the AOItour internally

```
public void angleEndInteractionEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e) {
    //AOItour has been modified, so i would  like to call own "myobj_EndInteractionEvt" 
    // so I can pass 
    // modified AOItour to it and  then  myobj_EndInteractionEvt would return AOI to
    // updateInteraction 
}
```

How to call callback **myobj_EndInteractionEvt** at the end **angleEndInteractionEvt**?

I have tried

```
public void angleEndInteractionEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e) {
  //some stuff
  myobj_EndInteractionEvt(sender,e);       
}
```

And it correctly goes to myobj_EndInteractionEvt but the issue is after that execution, program returns to angleEndInteractionEvt and does not go **updateInteraction** How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to trigger the Event that you've hooked up to. It's a little difficult understanding you're structure but typically you'd this in the class where you're event has been defined:

```
public class MyObj
{
   public void angleEndInteractionEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e) {
      // Do stuff
      if(EndInteractionEvt != null) {
         EndInteractionEvt(sender, e);
      }
   }
}
```

Typically however sender should be **this** - the instance that triggered the event.

At this point the following line will kick into play:

```
lo.myobj.EndInteractionEvt += (s, args) => updateInteraction(lo.myobj_EndInteractionEvt(s, args));
```

Firstly your myobj_EndInteractionEvt method is going to be called which should return the AOITour.

```
internal AOItour  myobj_EndInteractionEvt(vtkObject losender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff and return AOItour
    return AOItour;
}
```

The result of this should then get passed into updateInteraction that I've listed below so you're logging should now kick in.

```
public void updateInteraction(AOItour  tour)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tour.StateOfAOItour );  
    ClearMsg();
    etc...
}
```

What might be better and a little more readable (if they're defined on the same object) is to instead simply do:

```
public void angleEndInteractionEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e) {
   // Do stuff

   this.myobj_EndInteractionEvt(sender, e);
   if(EndInteractionEvt != null) {
         EndInteractionEvt(sender, e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`myobj_EndInteractionEvt` is a method, not an event. Instead of calling `myobj_EndInteractionEvt(sender,e);` directly, you need to trigger the event that calls it in your main class. So change `angleEndInteractionEvt` to:

```
public void angleEndInteractionEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e) {
  //some stuff
  EndInteractionEvt(sender, e);       
}
```

Comment: That is right, however how would you return AOItour as in `myobj_EndInteractionEvt` ?

Comment: Throwing the event will cause main to run the event handler `updateInteraction`.